# Renaming files based on their existing filename

Tags: powershell, cmd, rename, filenames

Trying to rename a few thousand files based on their existing filenames. All file are in various sub folders and were output by a program with a file name format of:
yyyy-mm-dd_filenameinfo.txt

Need to rename to:
dd-MMM-yyyy_filenameinfo.txt

An example would be:
2008-03-14_outputs.txt, being changed to
14-MAR-2008_outputs.txt

I understand the loss of sorting by date will occur from doing this, but it's a requirement for the submission process unfortunately.

I've done some research but I'm very unfamiliar with cmd line or powershell and I wasn't able to find a location where this question was asked already.

Comment: [`Rename-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-5.1) is the command you need. Copy a couple of files into a test directory and see if you can get it to work. Your question right now is not a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: While it's IMO not the best idea to rename files already in a proper sortable format, be it like you wish, `gci [12][09][0-9][0-9]-[01][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]_* -File -Rec|Ren -Newname {'{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}_{1}' -f (Get-Date ($_.Name.Split('_')[0])),($_.Name.Split('_')[1])} -whatIf` if the output looks OK, remove the trailing -whatif

Comment: @LotPings thanks for the answer! Is there a location where I can find more information on how that works? It does do exactly what I need it to but I'm always open to learning more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elaborating on my comment:

- gci -> [Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-5.1) using [wildcards/ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards?view=powershell-5.1)
- [-f format operater](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-5.1) to build newname
- [.split() method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-5.1) to split current names at the underscore into parts.
- [Get-Date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-5.1) cmdlet to convert split date into [datetime] type.
- Ren -> [Rename-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-5.1) accepts input directly from pipe, -NewName {script block} to evaluate new name per item

---

```
Get-ChildItem [12][09][0-9][0-9]-[01][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]_* -File -Recurse
```

Recursivly returns files names starting with a date from this/previous century

```
|Rename-Item -Newname {'{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}_{1}' -f (Get-Date ($_.Name.Split('_')[0])),($_.Name.Split('_')[1])}
```

Here:

```
$_.Name.Split('_')
```

Split's the name into two parts, the append index [0],[1] selcect's 1st,2nd part.

Get-Date converts the date into a [datetime] which is OTOH converted to the desired format by the `-f format operator` with [dd-MMM-yyyy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)